# Cannot get data from AJAX POST success function Express / mySQL

Tags: mysql, ajax, node.js, express

I have the following AJAX post call from the client side:

```
function get_game_id(){
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/game",
         data: {
             homeTeam: homeTeam,                     
             awayTeam: awayTeam,
             date:date
               },
         cache: false,
         success:function(results){
             alert(results.insertId)
         }
    })
}
```

The alert above is empty.
On the server I successfully insert the data to the DB with the following:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {

console.log(req.body.homeTeam,req.body.awayTeam);

var connection = mysql.createConnection(global.dbSettings);
connection.connect(function(err,res) {


    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("connected.");

        connection.query(
            "INSERT INTO game(homeTeam,awayTeam,game_date) VALUES (?,?,?)",
            [req.body.homeTeam,req.body.awayTeam,req.body.date],
            function (err, results) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Game Created with Game_ID:"+results.insertId);
                    console.log(req.body.homeTeam,req.body.awayTeam,req.body.date);

                }
            });


            connection.end(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("The connection could not be closed.");
                } else {
                    console.log("The connection is closed.");
                }
            });
    }


             });

       res.end();
});
```

The data is inserting correctly. The insertId() function is working correctly as The results.insertId is printing  to the console. I just cannot get it to the client.

I need this on the client side. I thought it should be accessible in the success function, but all that is there is 'TRUE'.

Can someone please, please explain to me how to send this back to the client?

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting this data that you just sent, back to the client, simply because you are not sending, but ending the response.

Either you just send it back what is inside `req.body`, or you query everything you just saved, back.
You can do: `res.send({homeTeam: req.body.homeTeam, ....}`

BTW, you are doing a "POST", it doesn't make sense getting data back from the server by doing it. What you should do is send a response of "200" to the client, and probably update your page with the data you just saved, because receiving 200, you know that the data was saved, so you don't waste time querying/sending back. You can do something like this:

```
res.status(200).send('data saved');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but what I am trying to achieve is to return the primary key of the last inserted row. There s a built in function with mySQL insertedId() which is exactly for that. The key to that function is that it always sends that id of the last row "I" inserted - and its done within the same connection, To use a GET could give you the id of a row someone else inserted (immediately after mine).  This is available to me within the function that contains the insert statement above (results.insertedId) - but I can't seem to pass it around anywhere, least alone back to the client.

Comment: Not sure if I understood well, but if I did, you could instead of doing a "POST", send your data by "GET", your parameters would be exposed in the url, not sure if this would a problem. Then, you simply return this primary key that you want back to the client. And you should send this response, inside your `else` statement in the callback function, otherwise you cannot guarantee the key is there.